# JdbcTemplate.queryforList() returns value but map.get returns null

Tags: java, dictionary, spring-jdbc

This is a very strange scenario I have come through and I have not been able to find out why.

This is my code.

```
public CreditCard getCardByNumber(String creditCardNumber) {
        CreditCard cc = new CreditCard();
        String sql = "Select * from credit_card where card_number=?";
        List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemp.queryForList(sql, new Object[] { creditCardNumber });

        for (Map<String, Object> row : rows) {
            for (Entry<String, Object> check : row.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(check.getKey());
                System.out.println(row.get(check.getKey()));
                System.out.println(check.getValue());
            }
        }
        return cc;
    }
```

The above code prints following:

```
card_id
null
1
customer_id
null
1
card_number
null
0699510593447478
cvv
null
231
card_date
null
07/22
card_status
null
Approved
credit_limit
null
8500
```

When I print the map, it prints `{card_id=1, customer_id=1, card_number=0699510593447478, cvv=231, card_date=07/22, card_status=Approved, credit_limit=8500}`

I tried `row.get(key)` which always returns null, I don't know why, but when I use entrySet to print the value, it gets the value.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce with an MCVE that has no database query and a single map.

Comment: You need a row mapper to map each row in the result set to Map<String, CreditCard>

Comment: @PeterHe, yes I am aware of that, but I am trying to get a List<Map<String, Object>> and map it manually to the creditcard.

Comment: If you create the map manually, change the return type from List<Map<String, Object>> to List<Object>

Comment: Any idea why get returns null even when the key matches.

Comment: I hope for your sake you're not actually storing CVVs and you that is not a valid PAN. Otherwise that's a serious PCI-DSS violation.

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall thanks for your concern. However, this is just some random data and I am trying to learn Spring JDBC. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because I used different Spring JDBC version and Spring version. Just changed Spring JDBC to Spring version and it worked like a charm.